# Log4net: Logger instantiation

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

guys.
I have a question regarding usage of loggers in log4net. When choosing between logger per class (static readonly field) and logger per instance (readonly field) what is a better approach? Personally, the only disadvantage I see when having logger per class is its instantiation:

```
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(
        System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
```

It doesn't look very nice because of reflection.
If I create logger in the following way:

```
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass))
```

there are chances that accidentally I will make copy/paste errors and instead of **typeof(MyClass)** I can supply **typeof(SomeOtherClass)**, which is bad.

When using logger per instance, I can use:

```
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType())
```

This approach doesn't use reflection and is free of copy/paste errors.

Are there any other thoughts on this?

Comment: What do you mean by **It doesn't look very nice because of reflection** ?

Answer (score 4):

Besides the fact that it would be better to use dependency injection, I think your approach is good. I have used this approach myself in the past.

Comment: Which one? Per instance? I also thought about DIing LogManager. However, it would mean that LogManager should be passed basically to every component, adding a compulsory parameter to constructors of these types, which complicates the class. Of course I'm hiding log4net behind a logging abstraction, however, I think that applying DI here is not worth, just because this is logging.